# Visual Basic.net code to take automatic screenshots

Tags: vb.net

I'm looking for visual basic.net code (for visual basic express) to take automatic screenshots (timeout=60 seconds) for application testing. But every code has a lot of bugs:

For example:

Try this code: http://mywiki.wikidot.com/forum/t-655

Or try this code: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=287803

Errors like:
Error   1   'Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)' has multiple definitions with identical signatures.

Error   2   'Private Sub InitializeComponent()' has multiple definitions with identical signatures.

Error   3   'components' is already declared as 'Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer' in this class.

Comment: Your error messages indicate a problem with your code, but you've not added any of your code to the question, so without that you probably won't get a good answer. However, looking at the error messages, I'd make a complete guess that you might have copied the code from one of those sites and then pasted it twice in the same file? I'd suggest that the easiest thing might be to start from the beginning.

Comment: I agree with ho1, I think you just copy-pasted the code twice... The error message tells you exactly what's going on!

Comment: Of course not. Have you tried the code???? And it didn't give any errors????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These links are old, the code in the first one was created with VS2003.  Before the VB.NET language acquired the *Partial* keyword.  To fix this you have to delete the Designer.vb file.

Click the "Show All Files" button in the Solution Explorer window.  Second button in the toolbar at the top of this window.  A [+] node appears next to your form, click it to open the node.  Right-click the Designer.vb file you now see and click Delete.

Comment: Application.Designer.vb, Resource.Designer.vb, Settings.Designer.vb PS: How do I get to the automatic screenshotcapture from here?